# (Refactor/Improve) Loop to make API calls and manupilate Array following the "no-loop-func"

Tags: reactjs, eslint, do-while

Despite looking and following numerous answers here at stackoverflow,
I have still failed to refactor this code to abide by the `ESLint no-loop-func`.

I keep getting the following warning, despite my efforts to refactor the code:

```sh
Compiled with warnings.

Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'lastResult', 'biologyBooks', 'page'  no-loop-func
```

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { apiFullCall } from '../../apiHelper';

const MyComponent = props => {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ total: 0, biologyBooksByAuthor: [] });
  let isLoaded = React.useRef(true);

  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  const authorID = sessionStorage.getItem('author_id');
  
  const getBooks = async() => { // fetch items

    let page = 1;
    let scienceBooks, biologyBooks; 

    // create empty arrays to store book objects for each loop
    let scienceBooks = biologyBooks = [];

    // create a lastResult object to help check if there is a next page
    let lastResult = { next: null };


    do { // the looping - this is what I have failed to refactor
      try {
        await apiFullCall( // Make API calls over paginated records
          '', 
          token, 
          'get', 
          `books/?author_id=1&page=${page}` 
        ).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            const { status, body } = res;

            if (status === 200 || status === 201) {
              
              lastResult = body; // assign lastResult to pick "next"
    
              body && 
                body.results && 
                  body.results.map(eachBook => { // we map() over the returned "results" array

                      // the author with queried "author_id" writes science books; 
                      // so we add each book (an object) into the science category

                      scienceBooks.push(eachBook);

                      // We then filter the author's biology books (from other science books)

                      biologyBooks = scienceBooks.filter(
                        ({ is_biology }) =>
                          typeof(is_biology) === "boolean" && is_biology === true
                      );

                      return null;
                    }
              );

              // increment the page with 1 on each loop
              page++;
            }
          }
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error while fetching data:', error));

      } catch (err) { console.error(`Oops, something went wrong ${err}`); }

      // keep running until there's no next page
    } while (lastResult.next !== null);

    // update the state
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, total: scienceBooks.length, biologyBooksByAuthor: biologyBooks,
    }));
  };
  
  React.useEffect(() => { // fetch science books by author (logged in)

    if (isLoaded && authorID) {
      getBooks();
    };
    
    return function cleanup() {...}; // clean up API call, on unmount

  }, [isLoaded, authorID]);

  return (
     // render the JSX code
  );

}
```

Please note that I actually declared the said variables `lastResult`, `biologyBooks` and `page` outside the "do-while".

Any help or clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function the warning is referring to is the `.then` callback, if you're using `async/await` stick to it, try removing the `.then` part by assigning the result to a variable instead and remove the unnecessary `.map`, you can concatenate previous results with spread operator or `.concat`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { apiFullCall } from '../../apiHelper';

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    total: 0,
    scienceBooksByAuthor: [],
  });
  const isLoaded = React.useRef(true);

  const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  const authorID = sessionStorage.getItem('author_id');

  const getBooks = async () => {
    // fetch items

    let page = 1;
    let scienceBooks = [];

    // create a lastResult object to help check if there is a next page
    let lastResult = { next: null };

    do {
      // the looping - this is what I have failed to refactor
      try {
        const res = await apiFullCall(
          // Make API calls over paginated records
          '',
          token,
          'get',
          `books/?author_id=1&page=${page}`,
        );
        if (res) {
          const { status, body } = res;

          if (status === 200 || status === 201) {
            lastResult = body; // assign lastResult to pick "next"

            // concatenate new results
            scienceBooks = [
              ...scienceBooks,
              ...((lastResult && lastResult.results) || []),
            ];

            // increment the page with 1 on each loop
            page += 1;
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Oops, something went wrong ${err}`);
      }

      // keep running until there's no next page
    } while (lastResult.next !== null);
    
    const biologyBooks = scienceBooks.filter(
      ({ is_biology }) =>
        typeof is_biology === 'boolean' && is_biology === true,
    );

    // update the state
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      total: scienceBooks.length,
      scienceBooksByAuthor: scienceBooks,
    }));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // fetch science books by author (logged in)

    if (isLoaded && authorID) {
      getBooks();
    }

    return function cleanup() {...}; // clean up API call, on unmount
  }, [isLoaded, authorID]);

  return (
    // render the JSX code
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, that was close - the warning still exists. The good news is that it drops `lastResult` and `page` from the warning list. So basically we're still being warned about the `biologyBooks` variable. Any more ideas on how to stamp that out?

Comment: @MwamiTovi I updated my answer with a full refactor, the `map` was unnecesarry since you just needed to concatenate results and I moved the filter for biology books after all results have been fetched because it makes more sense to do it once you have all the books

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm. So the culprit was the `map()`.. thanks. FYI: I updated this `state` field - `biologyBooksByAuthor: biologyBooks` that's why I needed the filter.